# SpyOn in Angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

First, I apologize.  I'm really new to Angular and am not sure I know enough to ask a good question, let alone provide some small working examples.

I'm trying to use spyOn in a unit test, and not having much luck.

Basically, my unit test calls a method on component that calls a service1, that calls another service2.

When I try to spyOn on service1, it doesn't use the mock value that I provide.  It calls the "real" ServiceProvidersHTTPService.getAllUsers and uses AppConfigService instead of MockAppConfigService.

I'll start by copying my Test.

```
describe('ProjectAnalystComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectAnalystComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectAnalystComponent>;
let service: ServiceProvidersHTTPService ;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [ ProjectAnalystComponent ],
  providers: 
  [
    ServiceProvidersHTTPService, 
    CurrentCreateProjectService, 
    NotificationService, 
    MessageService,
    ProjectLeadAnalystHTTPService,
      ExceptionService,
      {provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService }

  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectAnalystComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should create', () => {
    console.log("######### Did this run");
    let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ServiceProvidersHTTPService);
    spyOn(service, 'getAllUsers').and.returnValue('{}');

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Mock your service.

#### Explanation

In your testbed, you provide the actual service :

```
providers:[ServiceProvidersHTTPService, ...
```

This means you actually **call the real methods of your service**.

If you mock your service, like you did there :

```
{provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService }
```

Then you call **random functions that you declare in your mock**.

Another advantage of mocking, you get rid of the dependencies of your dependencies.

As you said, your service calls another service : if you mock your first service, **you don't have to add the dependencies of this service into your testbed**.

So, they way to go :

```
const mock = {
  provide: ServiceProvidersHTTPService,
  useValue: {
    getAllUsers: () => null
  }
};
```

In your testbed now :

```
providers: [mock, ...
```

In `useValue`, you must put **all the variables and all the functions of your actual service, and mock them**.

In this case, instead of making HTTP calls, your function `getAllUsers` will simply return null. You can make it return anything you want (the good practice is to return a value that is the same type of the value that should be returned).

Last piece of advice : your unit tests should test **only the functions and methods of your actual feature** (here being `ProjectAnalystComponent`). You should not test if your service call the other service here : you should test that **in the unit testing of your service**.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask !

Comment: Absolutely agree with your last point.. working on someone else's tests.. and they're definitely more "integration" tests than unit tests.    This fixed my immediately issue, but now other is failing.  I think I need a partialMock.

Comment: Well this looks like unit tests to me ! But if you have another issue, don't hesitate to make another question, or even edit this one (and notify me if you do)

Comment: Just to clarify.. so if I provide a service1, and provide {service2, useClass:mockservice2}, then service1 calls service2; but it doesn't respect the testbed provide?

Comment: If your component `ProjectAnalystComponent` doesn't have the second service in its constructor (as a dependency), then you don't even have to provide it. That's why mocking is important. Does your component use service 2, or does your component use service 2 through service 1 ?

Comment: The component uses service1 through service1.  Your example fixed my issue.. but the result that is returned by getAllUsers is an Observable.. so I had to create an observable to return instead of just null.  Thanks so much for your help @trichetriche  This was really getting me down.

Comment: So if it uses service 2 (I guess it's what you meant) through service 1, then you can delete the service 2 from your testbed, it will make no difference. And I did not know the signature of your function, sorry ... Glad I could help any way !